# how to compare strings in prolog

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog

I want to write a program in prolog that compares two strings or string lists. I want achieve the following:

```
if StringList A == StringList B
   {
     do this
   }
else
   do something else
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please search before asking. First link in google is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647506/code-to-compare-two-strings-in-prolog

Comment: A string might be several things in Prolog, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868)

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by `do this`? It hard to implement `doing somewhat` in Prolog, because all that you've got is facts and predicates.

```
?- (string1 = string2, X=1); (string1 \= string2, X=2).
X = 2.
```

Comment: Soory I did not explain properly. I need to write a program in prolog like this;    If (stinglistA == 'C', 'a', 'n','c', 'e','l') { M1= 'C' and M2 ='a') else M1 = M1 and M2 = m2

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it in a single line:

```
...
(A = B -> do this ; do something else)
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 /*SWI prolog code*/
string1(progga).
string2(ikra).

go:-
write("Enter your name"),
nl,
read(X),nl,
string1(Y),
X=@=Y,nl, write("Matched");
write("not Matched"),go2.

/*Another way to*/
go2:-                
string1(A),
string2(B),
A=@=B,nl, write("Matched");
write("not Matched").
```